# TCPDF add pages automate

Tags: tcpdf

I want to export a webshop order into pdf. I have a long html content, that includes text and tables also. The pdf file, that the program generates, now it only has 1 page, but if i take a look at the content, that would be about 2-3 pages.

What am i doing wrong?

```
    <?php
ob_start();
require_once('../files/connect.php');
require_once('../files/functions.php');
require_once('tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor(' ');
$pdf->SetTitle(' ');
$pdf->SetSubject(' ');
$pdf->SetKeywords(' ');
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
require_once('tcpdf/examples/lang/hun.php' );
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', 8, 13);
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_GET['id']);
$get = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT rendeles_adatok.*, user.user_id FROM rendeles_adatok LEFT JOIN user ON rendeles_adatok.rendeles_user_id = user.user_id
WHERE rendeles_id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
$a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get);
?>
<div style="background: #e5e5e5;">
    <table summary="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="8"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table summary="" width="800" align="center" cellspacing="10"
    style="background: #fff; color: #27160E; border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2; border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">

    <tr>
    <td>
    <h3 style="margin: 1em 0;"><strong>Tisztelt Adminisztrátor!</strong></h3>
    <p style="margin: 1em 0; color:#343434;line-height:20px;">Új vásárlás történt a http://teszt.hu oldalon.</p>
    <div class="content" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
        <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:0px;">
            <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                  <td><div align="center"><strong>Cikkszám</strong></div></td>
                  <td><div align="center"><strong>Termék név</strong> / <strong>Mennyiség</strong></div></td>
                  <td width="100"><div align="center"><strong>Egységár</strong></div></td>
                  <td><div align="center"><strong>Nettó</strong></div></td>
                  <td><div align="center"><strong>Áfa</strong></div></td>
                  <td><div align="center"><strong>Bruttó ár</strong></div></td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><div align="center">XXGTA005V</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Grand Theft Auto V PC Limited Edition  1<br />
                  1 db</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">25.400 Ft,-</div></td>
              <td><div align="right">20.000 Ft,-</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">5.400 Ft,-</div></td>
              <td><div align="right">25.400 Ft,-</div></td>

            </tr >

              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="2" bgcolor="#fff"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:0px;">

            <!--Ide, ebbe a cellába jön az összesítő táblázat, ha van kedvezmény-->
                <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="60%" rowspan="7"><div align="right">
                          <blockquote>
                            <h1>Összesen:</h1>
                          </blockquote>
                        </div></td>
                      <td><div align="left">Vásárlói kedvezmény</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">10%</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="left">Bruttó kedvezmény:</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">2.540 Ft,-</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="left">Nettó részösszeg:</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">18.000 Ft,-</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="left">Áfa:</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">4.860 Ft,-</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="left">Bruttó részösszeg:</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">22.860 Ft,-</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="left">Súly alapján, 25 kg-tól ingyen, alatta 490 Ft,-</div></td>
                      <td><div align="right">  <span>490 Ft,-</span> </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="left"><strong>Összesen bruttó</strong></div></td>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="right"><strong>23.350 Ft,-</strong></div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!--Összesítő kedvezményes táblázat vége-->



             </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
      <tr >
        <th align="left">Rendelés azonosító: 6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <th align="left">Átvételi mód: Súly alapján, 25 kg-tól ingyen, alatta 490 Ft,-</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
      <tr >
        <th align="left">Fizetési mód: Fizetés az üzletben készpénzzel</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
      <tr >
        <th align="left">Megrendelés dátuma: 2017-04-14 21:21:53</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h4>Megjegyzés</h4>
    <div style="text-align:justify; border:dashed 1px  #444; padding:10px; margin-bottom: 1em;">test</div>
    <br />
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4"  class="kapcs_adatok_2">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" align="left" nowrap="nowrap" >Megrendelő adatai</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Név:</td>
        <td colspan="2">teszt name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Telefon:</td>
        <td colspan="2">1111111111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">E-mail:</td>
        <td colspan="2">teszt@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="kapcs_adatok_2">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" align="left" nowrap="nowrap" >Számlázási adatok</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Számlázási név:</td>
        <td colspan="2">test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Cím:</td>
        <td colspan="2">2233 Bp Alter 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Adószám:</td>
        <td colspan="2">adószámom-123456789</td>
      </tr>



    </table>
    <br />
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="kapcs_adatok_2">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"  align="left">Szállítási adatok</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Név:</td>
        <td width="50%" >test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Telefon:</td>
        <td width="50%">1111111111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" nowrap="nowrap">Szállítási cím:</td>
        <td colspan="2">2233 Bp Alter 9</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="kapcs_adatok_2">
      <tr>
        <td><div class="footer" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
            <p style="margin: 1em 0;">Üdvözlettel:</p>
            <div>
              <p style="margin: 1em 0;"><strong>http://teszt.hu</strong></p>
            </div>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
        </div>

        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <table summary="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="8"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
ob_end_clean();
$file_nev = "rendeles-".$id.".pdf";
$pdf->Output($file_nev, 'D');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first parameter from *FALSE* to *TRUE*:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Oh, i didnt see that. Thank you! :)